# Adding a view to a NavigationController that isn't pushed to the stack

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I've added a UIToolbar to a NavigationController because I wanted to use the realtime blurring capabilities of the toolbar. I also wanted to customize the size - which means I can't use the toolbar built in to the NavigationController. I had to create my own and add it as a subview.

The problem is that I only want it on one particular view in my navigation stack. When I push subsequent views, the toolbar stays on the screen. I want it to be covered by the view pushed on the stack as the view slide-animates itself in to place.

How can I get it to do that without writing a custom animation?

Comment: why don't you just create the toolbar in the view of the one class that needs it, as opposed to doing it on the navigation controller?

Comment: because I want it to stay fixed over a UITableView.. I'd have to write code that 'moves' it or resizes it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self presentViewController:MyController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Presents a view like a modal. Exactly what I needed.